# Plot Pandas timeseries cumulative number of unique occurences in column over time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have an example dataset like:

```
   Datetime    value
   1.10.2020   x 
   1.10.2020   y
   2.10.2020   x 
   3.10.2020   z
   3.10.2020   x
   3.10.2020   y
   4.10.2020   x
   4.10.2020   y
   5.10.2020   x
   5.10.2020   z
```

I want to plot cumulative sum over time on how many times every unique value appears in column value. In this case there would be three lines in the graph, labels x,y,z. Y axis has the cumulative sum of occurrences(example x = 5) and x axis has the datetime column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the frequency of values in `value` with cumcount. Set the index to `Datetime` and plot the grouped values

```
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('value').cumcount() + 1
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)).groupby('value')['cumcount'].plot(style='x-')
plt.legend();
```

Out:

[image: value frequencies]